# Use of the comma in this phrase

Tags: punctuation, commas

Is the use of the comma before "in light of" necessary, optional or extra?

"This [book](https://www.larcier.com/fr/preliminary-references-to-the-court-of-justice-of-the-european-union-and-effective-judicial-protection-2020-9782807925427.html) focuses on this procedure from the perspective of the right to effective judicial protection, in light of Article 19(1), second subparagraph, TEU and Article 47 of the Charter of Fundamental Rights of the EU"

Answer (score 2):

It's optional, but useful.

This is a sentence with a short subject and verb, followed by a lot of prepostional phrases, some of which have internal structures that include more prepositional phrases.  For example "on this procedure" is a PP that relates to the main clause, but "of the right.." relates to the perspective and not to the main clause.  But "in the light..." relates back to the main clause again.

It is helpful to have a comma to indicate that the long, complex PP "from the perspective ... protection" has come to an end.

Comment: Is there a rule that says that commas can be used to avoid ambiguity in this context, @JamesK?

Comment: The rule for commas is that they can be used to avoid ambiguity, and to indicate the rhythm and intonation of phrases.